# Next.js: Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, next.js

I'm having a component called `Nav` inside `components` directory and it's code is some thing like below:

```
import Link from 'next/link';

const Nav = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <Link href="/">  <a> Home </a> </Link>
            <Link href="/about"> <a> About </a>  </Link>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Nav;
```

This gives me the error:

`Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.`

But if I remove the `<a>` tags within `<Link>` components, I can view the pages, but then in the console I'm getting a warning of:

`Warning: You're using a string directly inside <Link>. This usage has been deprecated. Please add an <a> tag as child of <Link>`

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks good. Are you sure you are receiveng the children error here and not somewhere else..

Comment: Remove the space between ```Link``` tag and ```a``` tag.. And give it like,  ```<Link href="/"><a> Home </a></Link>
            <Link href="/about"><a> About </a></Link>```

Comment: yes @Panther, If I remove those <a> tags, I can render my pages without errors. Having them won't even show me pages in the browser. But if i remove those <a> tags, I can see the pages, but in the console I get the above warning.

Comment: good catch @ManirajMurugan

Comment: wow thanks @ManirajMurugan,  It solved the issue. But that's strange having a space causing that issue. Now I Even tried having <a>s in seperate lines too, that also didn't cause any issue. Any way thanks :)

Comment: @AshanPriyadarshana, The next line is not considered as a space but if there is a space between both the tags then that is considered as child node(s) .. Posted answer with explanation with reason of removing white space between.. Hope it helps..

Comment: I had a comment inside the Link tag, and then that was being considered as a Child Node, breaking my whole app. Weird Stuff...

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This issue is due to the **space** between `<Link>` tag and `<a>` tag.

So change your code like,

```
        <div>
            <Link href="/"><a> Home </a></Link>
            <Link href="/about"><a> About </a></Link>
        </div>
```

Reason for the change:

> -> The `<Link>` can have only one child node and here the space between the `link` and `a` tag are considered as a child nodes.
>
> -> So there are two child nodes (One is space and another is `<a>` tag) which is invalid and hence such error occurs.

Comment: In my case I think the culprit was a space after a tag, followed by a note: (`</div> {/* So what this does is... */}`) THANK YOU. Those `<React.Fragment>`/`<></>` and `<TransitionGroup>` tags were not doing the trick

Comment: I was able to solve it with this solution, but I still need more clarification as to why spaces are considered as child nodes.

Answer (score 7):

Space between < Link > and < a > makes you error "Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Multiple children were passed to  with `href` of `/` but only one child is supported https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-multiple-children
Open your browser's console to view the Component stack trace."

Remove the space and it work fine.

```
import Link from "next/link";

const NavBar = () => {
    return (
        <nav>
            
           <Link href="/"><a>Home </a></Link>
           <Link href="/About"><a>About </a></Link>
            <Link href="/Contact"><a>Contact </a></Link>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default NavBar
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue as I was doing:

```
<Link href={`/tutorial/${tutorial.slug}`}>{tutorial.title}</Link>
```

The fix was to wrap it in an `a` tag:

```
<Link href={`/tutorial/${tutorial.slug}`}><a>{tutorial.title}</a></Link>
```

Answer (score 2):

**If the child is `<a>` tag then add `legacyBehavior`**. it will work

```
import Link from 'next/link'

function Legacy() {
  return (
    <Link href="/about" legacyBehavior>
      <a>About Us</a>
    </Link>
  )
}

export default Legacy
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a space that was considered as an undefined component

```
<Link href={to}><a className={'abc'}>{children}</a> </Link>
```

Removing the space, it was ok. 30 minutes lost only, thanks to experience and internet help.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue there were no problems with spaces rather I was passing an integer inside **Link**

```
    <Link href={{
           pathname: `/dashboard/people`,
          query: { idPerson: 123 }}}>
       {123}
   </Link>
```

I resolved this error by parsing the integer using **toString()** method

```
    <Link href={{
         pathname: `/dashboard/people`,
         query: { idPerson: 123 }}}>
      {(123).toString()}
   </Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Check if inner content is empty

In addition to the scenarios covered by other answers, this error **also** gets fired when there's no content in between `<Link>` opening and closing tags.

For example:

```
<Link href='/'></Link>  // i am an error
```

Answer (score 0):

Im following the NextJs tutorial and space is not only the culprit. Semi colon also.

```
// without space, this will also not work because of the semi-colon
    function FirstPost() {
      return (
        <>
          <h1> First Post </h1>
          <h2>
            <Link href="/">
              <a>Back to Home</a>;
            </Link>
          </h2>
        </>
      );

// with space but without semi-colon will not also work
function FirstPost() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1> First Post </h1>
      <h2>
        <Link href="/">
          <a> Back to Home </a>
        </Link>
      </h2>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I landed here because I was having a similar issue in my Next.js app, but I would get a **500 error in browser console** and **the `React.Children.only` error in my terminal** whenever I refreshed manually refreshed my app on any page.

The terminal output would provide a huge stack trace that pointed to `next-server` in my `node_modules` (`node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js`).

As it turns out, I was using `styled-components` with a boilerplate Next.js app setup by NX, and in my global app layout (`src/app/layout.tsx`), I had the `StyledComponentsRegistry` component as a parent of my main application, like so:

```
const RootLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <html lang="en">
    <body>
      <StyledComponentsRegistry>
        <>
          <div>header</div>
          <div>main content</div>
          <div>footer</div>
        </>
      </StyledComponentsRegistry>
    </body>
  </html>
);
```

It turns out that `React.Children.only`, and by extension `StyledComponentsRegistry`, did not consider the Fragment (`<>`) the child component since it's not rendered in the DOM when the page is built.

So instead, I replaced the wrapping Fragment (`<>`) with a div (`<div>`) and the error went away!

In other words, it looked like:

```
const RootLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <html lang="en">
    <body>
      <StyledComponentsRegistry>
        <div> {/* changed this <> to a <div> */}
          <div>header</div>
          <div>main content</div>
          <div>footer</div>
        </div> {/* changed this </> to a </div> */}
      </StyledComponentsRegistry>
    </body>
  </html>
);
```

(Hope this helps someone, and sorry to piggyback off an only somewhat related issue! There were no other questions addressing mine out there.)