# Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mern

I am working on a simple MERN stack application, it is very similar to To-Do list.

Once, I add the component below, I started to receive this error:
"Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child."
Also, the error disappears when I comment out the entire  element.

```
const RentalItem = ({ rental, onDeleteClick, onRentClick }) => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <ListGroup>
                <ListGroupItem>
                    <TransitionGroup>
                        <CSSTransition key={rental._id} timeout={1500} classNames="fade">
                            <p className="align-items-center mb-1">
                                {rental.name} / {rental.bikeType} / $ {rental.price}/hr
                            </p>
                            {!rental.isRented ? (
                                <div>
                                    <Button
                                        className="btn btn-primary"
                                        onClick={() => {onRentClick(rental._id)}}
                                    >
                                        Rent
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button
                                        className="btn btn-danger"
                                        onClick={() => {onDeleteClick(rental._id)}}
                                    >
                                        Delete
                                    </Button>
                                </div>
                            ) : (
                                <div>
                                    <Button
                                        className="btn btn-danger"
                                        onClick={() => {onRentClick(rental._id)}}
                                    >
                                    Cancel rent
                                    </Button>
                                </div>
                            )}
                        </CSSTransition>
                    </TransitionGroup>
                </ListGroupItem>
            </ListGroup>
        </Container>
    );
};
```

When I receive the error in the browser it points to the redux action code:

```
export const getRentals = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch(setRentalsLoading());
    axios.get("/api/rentals").then(res => 
        dispatch({
            type: GET_RENTALS,
            payload: res.data
        })
    )
}
```

Please, help out a newbie :)

Comment: There is nothing apparently wrong with what you pasted, can't help without more info

Comment: @ed' Thank you for your attention and willingness to help :) The answer below helped me solve my issue if you are interested. Have a great day ;)

Answer (score 2):

when you use CSSTransition, you should pass only one child, you can wrap your code with the Fragment component:

```
<CSSTransition key={rental._id} timeout={1500} 
    <>
       // your code is here
    </>
</CSSTransition>
```

please let me know if it is clear

Comment: It worked! I've wrapped the entire thing in a <div> and the error disappeared! Much appreciated. +1 to your karma :)

Comment: It's so infuriating--This is the popular solution I'm finding on Google and it is not working at all...No change whatsoever in the error...

Comment: I had a space within my `<CSSTransition>` tags to make a note. Deleting the note (and the space) resolved it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61651723/3511695