# NextJs Link component wrapping Image causes errors when mapping over array unless used in top level page component

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am trying to utilise NextJs's `<Link />` tag to wrap a NextJs `<Image />` in my application, to map over an array of data. If I place a `<Link />` in a top level page component everything plays nicely and renders correctly. However if I try to abstract this out into a sub component and then embed the sub component in the page component I receive errors telling me `Error: Multiple children were passed to <Link> with` href`of`/test `but only one child is supported https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-multiple-children` unless I remove all line breaks in the source code.

For example this works

```js
// pages/index.js
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';

export default function Home({links}) {
    return (
        <>
            <div id="container">
                <main>
                    {links.map(link => {
                        return <Link key={link.link} href={link.link}>
                            <a><Image src={link.imageUrl} width={400} height={400}/></a>
                        </Link>;
                    })
                    }
                </main>
            </div>

        </>
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/links');
    const links = await response.json();
    return {
        props: {
            links
        },
    }
}
```

This also works

```js
// pages/index.js
import Links from '../components/Links';

export default function Home({links}) {
    return (
        <>
            <div id="container">
                <main>
                     <Links links={links}/>
                </main>
            </div>

        </>
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/links');
    const links = await response.json();
    return {
        props: {
            links
        },
    }
}
```

```js
// components/Links.js
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function Links({links}) {
    return links.map(link => {
            return <Link key={link.link} href={link.link}><a><Image src={link.imageUrl} width={400} height={400}/></a></Link>;
        },
    );
}
```

However this fails

```js
// pages/index.js
import Links from '../components/Links';

export default function Home({links}) {
    return (
        <>
            <div id="container">
                <main>
                     <Links links={links}/>
                </main>
            </div>

        </>
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/links');
    const links = await response.json();
    return {
        props: {
            links
        },
    }
}
```

```js
// components/Links.js
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function Links({links}) {
    return links.map(link => {
            return <Link key={link.link} href={link.link}>
                <a>
                    <Image src={link.imageUrl} width={400} height={400}/>
                </a>
            </Link>;
        },
    );
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You can't have any extra spaces inside the `<Link>` tag. See [Next.js: Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61651497/next-js-error-react-children-only-expected-to-receive-a-single-react-element-c).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `nextjs` with `tailwindcss`.
When wrapping `Image` with `<></>`, my mouse didn't change to a little hand when hovering the element and clicking it does nothing.
And when wrapping with `<a></a>`, the image doesn't line up with other elements even using `flex justify-center items-center` on `Link`(at least in my case).

So this is my solution:

```
const iconSize=20;
<Link href="/">
      <div className="hover:cursor-pointer flex justify-center items-center">
            <Image
              src="/your_image.png"
              alt="clickable image"
              width={iconSize}
              height={iconSize}
            />
      </div>
</Link>
```

my nextjs version:

```bash
Next.js v12.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

try the code bellow

```js
const CustomLink = React.forwardRef(({ href, children, ...rest }, ref) => (
  <a href={href} ref={ref} {...rest}>
    {children}
  </a>
));
```

```js
// components/Links.js
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function Links({links}) {
   return links.map(link => {
            return <Link key={link.link} passHref href={link.link}>
                <Image src={link.imageUrl} width={400} height={400}/>
            </Link>;
       },
   );
}
```

Comment: You are importing Link from NextJS but not using it, I don't get what is ok with your answer.

Comment: sorry it was a typo fixed!