# Link component error with multiple childe elements when there are none

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a Link component in NextJs, it displays an error saying that there are multiple children with the same href, but that is not true. I don´t know how to fix the problem.

```
<div className='underline'>
   <Link href='/politica-de-privacidad'><a>Política de privacidad</a></Link>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have any extra spaces inside the `Link` tag. See [Next.js: Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61651497/next-js-error-react-children-only-expected-to-receive-a-single-react-element-c).

Comment: @juliomalves Fixed the problem, I had an extra space between the <a> tag. Thanks