# Adding a Link tag to a list of mapped values in next.JS

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, next.js, hyperlink, tags

I am using Next.js and I am trying to add a link tag to each mapped value but I am getting the error listed below:

**Unhandled Runtime Error**
Error: Multiple children were passed to  with `href` of `/genrepage/Action/28` but only one child is supported https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-multiple-children
Open your browser's console to view the Component stack trace.

How would I correct my code to get around this issue. The mapped element returns an object with a name and an id. I feel the error is in the actual line with Link but I am not sure.

My code is pasted below

```
return (
    <div className=" text-red-300;">
      {mygenres.genres.map((elem) => (
        <Link href={`/genrepage/${elem.name}/${elem.id}`}>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setMyselectedgenre(elem);
            }}
          >
            {elem.name}
          </button>
        </Link>
      ))}
     </div>
  );
```

and my relevant routing structure is

```
/genrepage
  [genre].js
    [id].js
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Next.js: Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61651497/next-js-error-react-children-only-expected-to-receive-a-single-react-element-c)? Make sure you don't have whitespaces anywhere inside the `Link` component.

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicked the button, it will be meanless routing so define a route object inside your mygenres.genres object. Such as;

```
{
  ...,
  route:"/3",
}
```

It will be easy to handle and already you're using id to route